# TRYING TO COLLECT A VALUE FROM NESTED JSON USING SPARK 1.6 (WrappedArray)

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, bigdata

I'm trying to transform a json file in a Dataframe, but i'm stuck in a field based on an array.
I'm using Spark 1.6 and Java. When I read a nested Json and transforming to a Dataframe, I can read some fields but when I try to enter in a specific path show me the error.

```
DataFrame df = spark.read().json(sc.wholeTextFiles("PATH").values());
```

I'm reading a json file.

```
df.select(col("orcamentos.itens")).printSchema();

root
 |-- itens: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- criticas: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigoCenario: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigodevolutiva: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- descricao: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- flagLiberacao: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- statusCenario: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- devolutivas: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- descricao: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- texto: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- tipo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- descricao: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- numeroItem: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rastreador: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- concessao: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- descricao: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dispositivo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- codigo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- descricao: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to print the field "numeroItem" using the follow:

```
df.select(col("orcamentos.itens.numeroItem")).show();
```

but i get the follow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'orcamentos.itens[numeroItem]' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, 'numeroItem' is of string type.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
```

When I tried to print only a node above (numeroItem's father), was returned the column from dataframe as shows below:

```
df.select(col("orcamentos.itens")).show();

+---------------------------------------+
|itens                                  |
+---------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([WrappedArray([5000,3,4,D|
+---------------------------------------+
```

How can I use this field if it's made of a WrappedArray? 
Later, I will need to explode dynamic this field/array.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the json input, you can do this:

In your json file, you have the array inside one big object. 
For spark to be able to treat the array as individual rows in a DataFrame, you should have the array as the root element.

So not `{"itens":[<element1>,...,<elementN>]}`, rather `[<element1>, ..., <elementN>]`